# How to disable next/prev button when slider have only one image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

When slider have one image then don't want next/prev button but if slider have more than 1 images then required next/prev button. Can you please suggest me JavaScript code to do. I know how to disable next/prev through controls false

```
controls : false
```

but it is also false when image have more than one image.
Here is my code,

```
<script>
var imgCnt = $('#images div').val(); //get images count.
if(imgCnt == 1){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
controls:false
});
}else{
controls:true
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have?

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code and it's working fine. Please try to your program. Using ternary operator.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.bxslider').bxSlider({
        controls: ($("#images div").length > 1) ? true: false,
    });
});
```

Comment: it will always be true as there will be only 1 ul with class bxslider

Comment: @RRR This code is working fine in my site. Changed `$('ul.bxslider').length` to `$('#image div').length`

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting up bxSlider if there is 1 image.
I have also change .val() to .size() to return the amount of elements selected.

```
<script>
var imgCnt = $('#images').size(); //get images count.
var useControls = true; // Show controls?
if(imgCnt == 1){
    useControls = false;
}
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    controls:useControls
});
</script>
```